# Getting error while importing win32com module

Tags: python

I installed the pywin32 module in my system. But when I import the "win32com" module getting the error as shown below.

Error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\script.py", line 1, in <module>
    import win32com.client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'
```

any idea on this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ModuleNotFoundError%3A+No+module+named+%27win32com%27 Just search for the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try install: `pip install pypiwin32`